Using Asset Manager Blender 4.2.3 LTS
I'm rather new to this and find myself getting hung-up on silly Things like:
I created an Asset Library from an existing Scene. I assigned a file Path in preferences.
When I create a New Document, I can see the assets, Textures, Etc. in the Asset Manager,
yet when I drag them into the New Scene, I don't see the Placement Grid and they are
automatically placed in the same location as the Scene that came from. At this Point, I
can not move or alter them and if I try to unlink them, they disappear.
I understand that I'm likely overlooking something very basic, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is great information. Thank you. However, how can I tell if they are grouped ? And How do I un-group them ? The collections they're stored within do not have the Asset Symbol.

... I've discovered that by duplicating the object, and making that as an Asset, It is now editable. (and I get the Placement Grid ) In the Library, the new Asset now has an Icon in the upper right hand Corner presumably denoting that it's editable. Do I have to do this with every Asset, Texture and Node Group ?

i edited my answer to explain asset icons. For the rest of your first comment, that would require to see the objects in their original file (rmb the asset in asset browser > open blend file) then screenshot the outliner from top parent to objects you want as assets and [edit] your question to add the screenshot

Since your objects get placed in different locations instead of where you dropped them, I reckon you have the objects in a collection, and you marked the collection as asset.
AFAIK the placement grid and bounding box' corners overlay, as well as snapping the dropped asset on vertices, is only available with object-type assets:

It isn't available on collection-type assets for now. Hopefully in future Blender versions.
If you want each of your objects to be an individual asset, you should mark the said objects as assets, instead of the containing collection. Use the collection only when you have a bunch of objects that make up an asset (like a couch, or a character with its animation rig).
As to why you can't move your objects, it's probably because they are within a collection and that you linked that collection into the scene. Blender offers multiple ways to "import" data from another blend file, mainly link and append. The asset browser lets you chose once for all in the preferences, but also dynamically in its header:

Link is basically a non-modifiable instance of an asset. It is loaded once in memory and can be reused as many times as you want with no extra memory cost, bus isn't modifiable (unless you add a library override on it to unlock some of it).
Append is your regular import that creates a full copy of your asset into your current scene. It is fully editable, but costs its full weight of memory.
Hence, you need to think wisely how your multiple-objects assets are gathered or not into a collection, or using armatures to place their individual parts, or use either link and append.
Assets Icons
Icons to the bottom left corner tell the asset type:

Mesh objects have mesh objects icons, collections have collections icons, and you have node groups, actions (poses/animations), materials, ...
The top right icon of a file with a pen tells the asset is from the current file:

